# Does the contact form 7 plugin of wordpress filter unnecessary data from input fields?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

So does this plugin remove unnecessary tags and avoid hacks, is there a way to do regex and remove like we do in our normal forms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function `wpcf7_autop`  clean the unnecessary tags and hacks.

Here is the file https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/formatting.php

Comment: how do i use ? do i have that in the input syntax? or please give me an example i am a starter wp programmer

Comment: @user5676973 No, just configure the plugin in the wordpress administration interface and everything works out of the box, if you want to add custom regex you can use this addon github.com/m0xds/contact-form7-custom-validation

Comment: still am not getting it. I am really sorry because i cant see where to put it in the admin interface? Any step by step tutorials for that? Its really hard to work on interfaces, if it was plain code it would be so good but, using just php  is time consuming for me and people pay less here so i started wp developement.

Comment: i just added define('WPCF7_AUTOP', true); in wp-config.php. Is that fine, anyways still unable to filter anything.

Comment: What you want to filter? However, here is the [getting started](http://contactform7.com/getting-started-with-contact-form-7/) guide of contact form 7. It works with [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode)

Comment: Does contact form 7 filter things like tags and unnecessary symbols that hackers use to hack into websites

Comment: I was just trying to filter those